# How open a resource from php hiding real path emulating .htaccess rewriterule

Tags: php, .htaccess

if in `.htaccess` i have:

```
RewriteRule ^filename$ real/path/filename.pdf [L]
```

Typing as URL: `www.mydomain.com/filename` i open `filename.pdf` located in `real/path/` without problem! But... having:

```
RewriteRule ^filename$ load.php?file=real/path/filename.pdf [QSA,L]
```

How i open `real/path/filename.pdf` directly from `load.php`?

I have tried with:

```
#FILE: LOAD.PHP
<?php
   fopen ( $_GET[ "file" ], "r");
?>
```

and:

```
<?php
   print file_get_contents( $_GET[ "file" ] );
?>
```

But all failed. Now, i don't want use `header()` becouse i want **HIDE** the `real/path/filename.pdf`.

In other words, i want emulate action of:

```
RewriteRule ^filename$ real/path/filename.pdf [L]
```

Where `real/path/filename.pdf` **NOT IS** visible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

here you can find most used MIME types
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

In this way:

```
<?php

   // for security reasons
   $your_enabled_files=[
     "file1"=>["path"=>"your/path/for/thisfile1.pdf", "mime"=>"application/pdf"],

     "file2"=>["path"=>"your/path/for/this/file2.ext", "mime"=>"mimeyouwant" ],
     
     "file3"=>["path"=>"your/path/for/this/file3.ext", "mime"=>"mimeyouwant" ]
    
   ];

   if (array_key_exists (  $_GET[ "file" ]  , $your_enabled_files )){   
      header("Content-Type: ".$your_enabled_files[$_GET["file"]]["mime"]);
      echo file_get_contents( $your_enabled_files[$_GET["file"]]["path"]);
   }else{
      header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
      echo "404 File not found";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it not help me. It return the binary of the file to video but not open it. I need open file.

Comment: oh ,  you need to set the content-type header for every type of file you want to serve.

Comment: Can to do a example? Content type should be: "Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=UTF-8". How i launch it?

Comment: The way you indent your array definition is very bad practice. please consider using a standard indentation instead to enhance the readability.

Answer (score 1):

Use function `getcwd()` to find out the working directory within `load.php`. Something like:

```
<?php var_dump(getcwd());
```

Now you will be able to figure out the correct path to the files you want to serve.

BEWARE: Strictly filter the requested files, because otherwise an attacker could get access to files you wouldn't like to.

Comment: Done but not solved. The file not is served.